# int8 scipy sparse matrix creation errors creating int64 structure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, scipy

```
Python 3.5.4 (default, Sep 27 2019, 09:11:05) 
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux

numpy==1.18.0
scipy==1.4.1
```

I've been trying to use scipy.sparse to create a very large square matrix, where the lower left half of which is zeros, and the upper right half is ones.  I've used dtype `int8` to represent each element (it appears using a boolean would result in 8-bit storage so no point using this).

For fairly large matrices (say 16300x16300) both methods described below work well.

To do this I've tried various ways of creating the ones and then using `triu` to create the triangle of ones.

The problem is when I try to produce an array of say 522659x522659, the ones are created correctly, but the `triu` fails with the following errors.

Note I have 750gb of memory of which 4gb is used before execution.  So the memory error is true insofar as I won't be able to create and array of 2 or 4tb!  But the point is I shouldn't need anything like that size of allocation to store the numbers I want as single bytes.

**My questions are:**

1. Why do both methods attempt construct an object of type `int64` when I have fed it data of type `int8`?
2. How can achieve creating the 522659x522659 matrix, given I should have ample memory to do so?

**Attempt 1:**

Memory use peaks at ~260gb - which makes sense as this creates 522659*522659 = 273,172,430,281 ones before only taking the top half.  So it's inefficient in that it produces twice as many ones as it needs to, but the error happens during the call to `scipy.sparse.triu` not in the generation of the ones.

```
Length:522659
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "16.py", line 10, in <module>
    m = generate_sparse_pattern(522659)
  File "16.py", line 8, in generate_sparse_pattern
    return sp.triu(np.ones((length,length), dtype=np.int8))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/sparse/extract.py", line 162, in triu
    A = coo_matrix(A, copy=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py", line 191, in __init__
    self.row, self.col = M.nonzero()
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 3.98 TiB for an array with shape (273172430281, 2) and data type int64
```

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.5                                  

import scipy.sparse as sp
import numpy as np

def generate_sparse_pattern(length):
    print("Length:" + str(length))
    return sp.triu(np.ones((length,length), dtype=np.int8))

m = generate_sparse_pattern(522659)
```

**Attempt 2:**

This time the ones creations takes ~134gb, but when adding the ones to the matrix the memory usage continues to climb to ~387gb where it remains constant, before crashing in a similar fashion to Attempt 1.  Note the size of the `int64` it tries to create is half the size of Attempt 1, which was my intention - to produce only the ones that I needed, but the real memory use up until this point is larger!

```
Length:522659
Create Matrix
Create Ones
Add ones to matrix
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "16.py", line 20, in <module>
    m = generate_sparse_pattern(522659)
  File "16.py", line 17, in generate_sparse_pattern
    matrix[np.triu_indices_from(matrix,0)] = ones
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in triu_indices_from
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py", line 1017, in triu_indices_from
    return triu_indices(arr.shape[-2], k=k, m=arr.shape[-1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py", line 984, in triu_indices
    return nonzero(~tri(n, m, k=k-1, dtype=bool))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in nonzero
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 1896, in nonzero
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'nonzero')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 61, in _wrapfunc
    return bound(*args, **kwds)
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.99 TiB for an array with shape (136586476470, 2) and data type int64
```

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.5                                       

import scipy.sparse as sp
import numpy as np

def generate_sparse_pattern(length):
   print("Length:" + str(length))
   print("Create Matrix")
   matrix = sp.lil_matrix((length,length), dtype=np.int8)
   print("Create Ones")
   ones = np.ones((length * (length+1) // 2), dtype=np.int8)
   matrix[np.triu_indices_from(matrix,0)] = ones
   return matrix.tocsr()

m = generate_sparse_pattern(522659)
```

Comment: Look at the code for `sp.triu`.  I've never used it. In the second `np.triu` is creating a very large array of all the upper indices.

Comment: `np.triu_indices_from` calls `np.tri` to create a mask (which is what I want!) - but the `min_int` in  `m = greater_equal.outer(arange(N, dtype=_min_int(0, N)), arange(-k, M-k, dtype=_min_int(-k, M - k)))` -  creates an array for holding the max idx, not than the 1s I want - for large arrays will be `int64`.  The "outer inequality" for creating triangular arrays is a neat trick, but memory hungry if elements are smaller than the index that ref them.  The `scipy.triu` solution isn't the same, I'm still not sure why it's inefficient - I suspect `mask = A.row + k <= A.col` does something similar?

Comment: My comment above is wrong. The problem is `int64` indices, but not as described. Each `arange` passed to `outer` remains a 1D array of `int64`, and isn't used to create NxM array of `int64`.  See answer below for an explanation of why sparse arrays use of `int64` indices is the real issue.  The use of `greater_equal.outer` creates an NxM array of `bool`, each element taking the same space requirements as `int8`.  The use of `np.tri` is actually relatively efficient for this problem - see comments on answer below.  See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is a work in progress.

Sparse matrices are space and time efficient when they are sparse.  Rough experience suggests that 10% sparsity, or less is good.  50% is not.

The core of this package was developed for linear algebra work (e.g. finite element ODE solutions).  The `csr` format in particular is optimized for matrix multiplication.  It uses compiled code (`cython`), which uses the standard `c` data types - integers, floats and doubles.  In `numpy` terms that means `int64`, `float32` and `float64`.  Selected formats accept other dtypes like `int8`, but maintaining that dtype during conversions to other formats and calculations is difficult.

Row and column indices are stored explicitly (for `coo` and `csr`), and use `int32` or `int64` depending on the shape of the matrix.

===

Your first approach:

```
In [34]: np.ones((5,5),np.int8)                                                          
Out[34]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=int8)
In [35]: M = sparse.coo_matrix(_)                                                        
In [36]: M                                                                               
Out[36]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int8'>'
    with 25 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [37]: print(M)      # show all 25 elements                                                                      
  (0, 0)    1
  (0, 1)    1
  (0, 2)    1
  (0, 3)    1
  (0, 4)    1
  (1, 0)    1
  ...
  (4, 3)    1
  (4, 4)    1
In [38]: sparse.triu(M)                                                                  
Out[38]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int8'>'
    with 15 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

`triu` on the dense array does the same thing.

Your memory error occurs when `triu` is turning that array into a `coo` matrix (in preparation for selecting the subset of rows/cols)

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/sparse/extract.py", line 162, in triu
    A = coo_matrix(A, copy=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py", line 191, in __init__
    self.row, self.col = M.nonzero()
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 3.98 TiB for an array with shape (273172430281, 2) and data type int64
```

273172430281 is `length**2`, the total number of ones in the original array.  Because of the shape it has to use the larger `int64` dtype.  The dense array just has to have space for 273172430281 `int8` values, but the sparse adds this `int64` indexing array.  `triu` will cut all those arrays in half (depending on k) but that's still larger than the dense array.

===

In the 2nd case

```
tri(n, m, k=k-1, dtype=bool)
```

makes the (n,m) boolean mask.

```
nonzero(~tri(n, m, k=k-1, dtype=bool))
```

finds the indices of the nonzero elements of that mask.  It needs similar space for that

```
(136586476470, 2) and data type int64

In [43]: np.triu_indices_from(np.ones((5,5)))                                            
Out[43]: 
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4]))
```

is a 2 element tuple, with 15 element row and column index arrays.

A dense array takes up much less space, even though it saves both the 0s and the 1s:

```
In [46]: np.triu(np.ones((5,5),np.int8))                                                 
Out[46]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=int8)
```

Comment: So it looks like the problem is the creation of the intermediate COO matrix.  It creates `row` and `col` arrays of `int64` values that each have  `n * (n + 1) // 2` elements.

Comment: A `csr` format matrix would be a bit smaller, with the `indptr` attribute only having one value per row (+1).  But it doesn't have a simple `triu` solution.  And making a `csr` matrix from a dense one still requires passing through the `coo` format.

Comment: Thanks - Switching to np.triu in attempt 1 gives `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 254. GiB for an array with shape (522659, 522659) and data type int8` when memory allocation is at ~500gb.  Looking at the source it looks like 3 arrays might be created - a) the `ones`, b) the `tri` mask, c) the output of `triu`'s `where` clause.  Meaning ~762gb is needed at peak memory usage to construct the final array.  My guess is that I can reduce this by calling `tri` directly as the mask is actually what I want (but with the upper and lower triangles switched).  I'll give this a go.

Comment: The `indices` array of a CSR matrix will require `n * (n + 1) // 2` elements.  For `n = 522659`, with 64 bit integers, `indices` will requires 1092 GB.

Comment: Yep - sparse matrices are not a good idea with 50% use.  I can limit the peak memory usage of a non-sparse solution to ~254gb, changing Attempt 1's to `return (~np.tri(length,k=-1,dtype=np.bool))`.  This casts correctly to 0/1 when multiplied against an `int8` matrix.  I think this is the smallest footprint I'll manage for the generation.  The only snag I have now is when multiplying this matrix against a 1x522659 vector (using `matmul`, `dot`, `inner`, or `einsum`), scipy seems to generate another temp ~254gb matrix despite the result being a 1x522659 vector, arguably a different question tho